# ClassNotFoundException While adding external packages.

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

I am working on Android project, I have integrated some external packages. When I run the project I get the following error.

I have added need classes in Manifest file.

```
04-22 12:02:46.798: E/AndroidRuntime(27770): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.capmem-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.capmem-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

04-22 12:02:46.798: E/AndroidRuntime(27770):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
```

When I debug the code the control is coming upto setContentView(R.layout.create_event); when I click on F6 it is crashing.

I am not understanding the exact problem.

please help..

Comment: is ActionBar class part of some external library / jar ?.

Comment: Your external jar needs to be added to the classpath of your project .